# Как в функции обратиться к переменной на уровень выше? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дана структура:

```
def a():
    aaa = 0
    .....
    for i in range(3):
        def b(c):
            if c == 1:
                aaa += 1
        b(1)
        ...
        def g(c):
            if c == 1:
                aaa += 1
        g(1)
        ...
    print(aaa)
a()
>>> 0 
а нужно чтобы выводилось 2
```

Как можно сделать, чтобы функция `b()` перезаписывала переменную `aaa` в пространстве имен функции `a()`. global не сработало.

Comment: Не хочу вас расстраивать, но у вас a() - это совсем не класс

Comment: Да, меня поправили, ошибся, сорри

Answer (score 1):

[области видимости](https://stepik.org/lesson/24460/step/1?unit=6766)

```
def a():
    aaa=0
    def b():
        nonlocal aaa
        aaa+=1
    b()
    print(aaa)
a()
```

Comment: Это называется не уровнями, а неймспейэсами (namespaces)

Comment: понял, спасибо, у меня ошибка появляется синтаксическая: `name 'aaa' is assigned to before nonlocal declaration`, вообще пойму ее причину.. Не знаете в чем может быть дело?

Comment: дайте исходный код

Comment: изменил немного первоначальный код, у меня структура глубже и в самой функции `а()`, есть много кода помимо функций `b()` и `g()`, в том числе и код который запускает `b()` и `g()`

Answer (score 1):

Не надо использовать `global` и `nonlocal` без очень крайней нужды.

Используйте **настоящиее** классы:

```
class A:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.aaa = 0
    
    def b(self):
        self.aaa += 1
    
    def print_result(self):
        print(self.aaa)


a = A()
a.b()
a.print_result()  # Напечатает 1
```

Comment: Изменил немного первоначальный код, дело в том что у меня еще много кода в самой функции a(), помимо переменной aaa, как это все в __init__ засунуть непонятно, возможно ли классом А обернуть и функцию a(), не избавляясь от нее?

Comment: не знаете как можно сделать?

Comment: Не обязательно всё засовывать в `__init__`. Вы можете создавать сколько угодно методов внутри класса (примерно как я сделал метод print_result в моём примере). А вообще - просто найдите нормальный саомучитель по питону и почитайте про классы и ооп, вам станет гораздо проще.